# ListView not scrolling in positioned Widget

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, scroll, position

I currently have a stack with a backdrop for my `AppBar` and the contents of my page.
I'm displaying a `Container` in the center of the page, positioned with the `Positioned` widget, which contains a grid/listview.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: VehicleScreenAppBar(
        title: title,
        context: context,
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (contxt, vehicleListConstraints) {
          return Stack(
            overflow: Overflow.visible,
            children: <Widget>[
              AppBarBackDrop(constraints: vehicleListConstraints),
              Positioned(
                top: vehicleListConstraints.maxHeight * .15,
                left: (vehicleListConstraints.maxWidth - vehicleListConstraints.maxWidth * .9) / 2,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: vehicleListConstraints.maxHeight * .6,
                  width: vehicleListConstraints.maxWidth * .9,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 50,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Text('text'),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: Screenshot]

The problem that I am running into is that the grid/listview do not scroll when I have `Positioned` widget AND I have explicitly named any BUT NOT ALL of its constructors, i.e. `top:`, `bottom:`, `left:`, `right:`. (I'm lazily building the grid/listview lazily via builder).

I have a work around/hack where I remove the `Positioned` and replace it with a `PageView`. The `PageView` then has a `children: <Widget> [  Container()  ]` that I then position via the margin constructors' `top:` and `left:`.

This will work for now, but not something that I want to implement for production. How can I get the grid/listview to scroll within a `Positioned` widget WITHOUT naming all of its constructors?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For scroll-able widgets wrapped inside the positioned widget, you should give all the parameters (left, right , top , bottom) of Positioned widget a value then it will work.

```
 Positioned(
              top: 20.0,
              left: 20.0,
              right:0.0,
               bottom:0.0

              child: SizedBox(
              //what ever code is)),
                )
                  )
```

Answer (score 3):

This display the `Container` in the center of the page

```js
Positioned(
  top: 0.0,
  left: 0.0,
  right: 0.0,
  bottom: 0.0,
  child: //your code
)
```